# Time series binary classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, time-series, lstm

Which deep learning architecture and algorithms do you most recommend for time series classification problem?

Of course LSTM, I am looking for state of the art papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://paperswithcode.com/task/time-series-classification/latest -> You can find all the state-of-the-art papers along with code for Time Series Classification.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.04356.pdf -> This paper provides an in-depth review of some deep learning architectures for Time Series Classification.

Hope it helps!